# bitmap transparency in Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++, windows, image, visual-studio, winapi

I'm puzzled on this one.  I use a program recommended on the forums to convert 32bit PNG to 32bit bitmaps with alpha channel.  I add these to the resource editor and place them via the toolbox onto a Dialog.  I have read (what I thought was extensively) on bitmap transparency and the limitations in Visual Studio.
What's puzzling for me is that I add the picture control via the Visual Studio resource editor to my dialog box.  For example, I have two red balls, one in 24bit bitmap and one with 32bit bitmap.  In the test mode of visual studio and when opening the .rc with the resource editor the transparency looks fine.
[image: Test mode of visual studio]

However, when I call DialogBox programmatically, I don't get transparency.

```
DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
    NULL, DialogProc);
```

[image: Dialog when DialogBox is called programmatically]
When I click the test button in Visual Studio, it must be calling a routine DialogBox or similar to show the bitmap.  When I place the bitmap in the resource editor to the dialog it shows transparency.  What is it Microsoft does that I'm not doing?
I'm developing without MFC, intentionally.  Is that the issue, only in MFC can Dialogbox's be loaded with transparency (I realize it reduces to CreateWindowEX).
I realize that various bitblt methods also can be used.  Is that what Visual Studio does behind the scenes?  Also reviewed material on WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC etc.
What do you all think?  Is there some simple way to call DialogBox and get transparent BMPs on the dialog? Or we're all forced to use MFC? or the user has to write the routines to erase the background/paint etc.

It seems a bit odd to me that without an image with transparency, a dialogbox is easy.  Need a non-square image? That's somehow a problem. Now the software engineer has to add lots of code to the Dialog Callback or program.  Seems more of a bug to me.

Thank you for your review.

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <winuser.h>
 #include "resource.h"


 INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM   lParam)
  {
  int wmId, wmEvent;

  switch (message)
   {
   case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDOK:
        EndDialog(hwnd, LOWORD(wParam));
        break;
    case IDCANCEL:
        EndDialog(hwnd, LOWORD(wParam));
        return TRUE;

    }

case WM_PAINT:
    break;

case WM_DESTROY:
    EndDialog(hwnd, LOWORD(wParam));
    break;
}
return FALSE; 
}


 int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
 LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
 int       nCmdShow)
 {


DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
    NULL, DialogProc);

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code. DialogBox does not need a messageloop, Don't call DefWindowProc in the dialog proc and remove the (DLGPROC) cast, fix the code, don't hide brokenness with casts!

Comment: Consider reading the documentation. A dialog procedure has a different signature, namely a boolean return value. The main difference between Visual Studio and your code probably is, that yours is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I cut and pasted an example I could show to the public, so it was not perfect.  I've updated the code based on the comments so that is not a distraction.  I do not see anything wrong with the DLGPROC cast, it is common use.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: the code compiles and works in Visual Studio 2013.  If there is a way to upload a zip of the project, I would do so.  Simple DialogBox with transparent image.   The point of the question is,  Visual Studio shows transparent bitmaps without issue, a call to the standard DialogBox function should do the same.  It does not.

Comment: thanks again for comments. I have fixed the return values so those are not a distraction.  The focus I believe should be on why a call to DialogBox does not support transparent bitmaps.

Comment: Code in question is still wrong. Remove the cast in your `DialogBox` call. The compiler will issue an appropriate error. You can fix that error by providing the correct [dialog box procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644995.aspx#procedures) signature. This question has been downvoted, because it is not useful. You are asking why buggy code exhibits different behavior than correct code.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I'm surprised that the cast on a call back is raising concern since the issue being asked is related to a bug in Visual Studio when painting bitmaps with transparency in a dialog box.    I've removed the cast.

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this.  Please re-consider the downvote.  The question is useful to the community as why does a call to DialogBox result in a visually poor transparent bitmap display when the 32 bit map with transparency is understood within Visual Studio.  I'm sure I'm not the only one using transparency.  I don't see buggy code, please identify if you see anything further.

Comment: The cast was there to hide a bug. Asking you to fix the bug should not be a surprise to you. The question is fairly useless. It's asking us to guess about an implementation detail of Visual Studio. It's a preview feature, that makes not guarantees, other than providing something, that tries to closely resemble the final result. An answer to your question does not aid anyone in implementing (alpha) transparency. There are lots of ways to implement (alpha) transparency, and those that believe they need it, know how to do it. They don't need to know how Visual Studio is implemented to do so.

Comment: If you believe that this is a bug in Visual Studio, you are free to file a defect report with the vendor of the product. Stack Overflow is not the vendor of Visual Studio.

Comment: If you have some real technical help to offer, then please do.  Otherwise, the comments are not useful.  I'm asking the community to help with a problem in why a call to DialogBox does not yield useable results for 32 bit transparent bitmaps.  Someone may have encountered this before and a solution is obvious.  It may be a known bug.  These types of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: Simple solution: add an application manifest specifying common controls 6.0.0.0. I updated my answer...

Comment: @IInspectable please consider removing the downvote on the question.  Your assertion that the code is buggy or broken never had any legs.  Many can benefit from the question and the answer provided.

Comment: It's a poor question. It goes on and on and on about Visual Studio, the Resource Editor, some undisclosed external program, without ever touching the real problem you were trying to solve. It detours into speculations about implementation details of Visual Studio. None of that is relevant. This question can be rewritten into a single paragraph, asking how to display a 32-bit ARGB image in a static control through a resource script. And I'm fairly sure that question has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @IInspectable Though the question could be made more concise, it's pretty obvious glancing at the question what it is asking.  If you know of another similar question, can you post a link?

Comment: Thank you. And if I left out any detail, then there would be a complaint that there wasn't enough detail.  To go on and on, like that just isn't helpful to the community.  Reasonable people were able to answer the question spot on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to the problem which both have advantages and disadvantages.

**Solution 1** fixes the original problem stated by the OP by simply adding an **application manifest** file to the resources. There is no coding required for this solution. The transparency achieved with that solution is not perfect, but is supported on all Windows versions since Windows XP.

**Solution 2** is more advanced as it creates a **layered child window** that provides true transparency of the image over the dialog background aswell as any overlapping child controls. The disadvantages are that at least Windows 8 is required and a decent amount of non-trivial code must be written (but you are lucky as I already did this for you ;-)).

## Solution 1 - add an application manifest

The native static control supports bitmaps with alpha transparency only if you add an **application manifest** that specifies **common controls version 6.0.0.0**. From the "old-school" look of the controls in your screenshot we can see that you don't have such a manifest yet.

Save the following snippet into a file called "manifest.xml" and put it into your application resource folder. In Visual Studio, right-click your project, go to "manifest tool" > "input and output" > "additional manifest files" > enter relative path of "manifest.xml" without quotation marks.

```xml
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application>
        <!-- Windows 10 --> 
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        <!-- Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        <!-- Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
    </application>
  </compatibility>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

No further coding is required, just select the bitmap resource for the picture control (which actually is a static control) in the resource editor.

The bitmap to use should be a 32 bpp bitmap, bottom-up row order, non-premultiplied alpha. If you use [PixelFormer](http://www.qualibyte.com/pixelformer/) to convert from PNG, use format A8:R8:G8:B8 (32 bpp) without selecting the other check boxes in the export dialog. If you use [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/) to convert, simply save as BMP, it will use this format by default.

**Result:**

[image]

As we can see, we only get "fake" transparency. Any other controls underneath the image will be clipped at the boundaries of the static control.

## Solution 2 - using a layered child window

True transparency is possible using a [layered child window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#layered) (WS_EX_LAYERED extended style). This is supported since Windows 8. It requires some coding though.

I wrapped the required code into a function `SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource()` which might be called from the WM_INITDIALOG handler of the dialog. The function throws any error as `std::system_error` exception, so you must **add a try/catch block** to handle the errors (this is shown further below in the "usage" example).

```
#include <system_error>

/// Turn given window into a layered window and load a bitmap from given resource ID 
/// into it.
/// The window will be resized to fit the bitmap.
/// Bitmap must be 32bpp, top-down row order, premultiplied alpha.
///
/// \note For child windows, this requires Win 8 or newer OS
///       (and "supportedOS" element for Win 8 in application manifest)  
///
/// \exception Throws std::system_error in case of any error.

void SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource( 
    HWND hwnd, UINT bitmapResourceId, HINSTANCE hInstance = nullptr ) 
{
    // Enable "layered" mode for the child window. This enables full alpha channel 
    // transparency.

    // GetWindowLong() won't reset the last error in case of success.
    // As we can't judge from the return value of GetWindowLong() alone if 
    // the function was successful (0 may be returned even in case of
    // success), we must reset the last error to reliably detect errors.
    ::SetLastError( 0 ); 
    DWORD exStyle = ::GetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE );
    if( !exStyle )
    {
        // NOTE: Call GetLastError() IMMEDIATELY when a function's return value 
        // indicates failure and it is documented that said function supports 
        // GetLastError().
        // ANY other code (be it your own or library code) before the next line 
        // must be avoided as it may invalidate the last error value.
        if( DWORD err = ::GetLastError() )
            throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>(err), 
                std::system_category(),
                "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: Could not get extended window style" );
    }

    // SetWindowLong() won't reset the last error in case of success.
    // As we can't judge from the return value of GetWindowLong() alone if 
    // the function was successful (0 may be returned even in case of
    // success), we must reset the last error to reliably detect errors.
    ::SetLastError( 0 ); 
    if( !::SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED ) ) 
    {
        if( DWORD err = ::GetLastError() )
            throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>(err), 
                std::system_category(),
                "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: Could not set extended window style" );
    }

    // Use RAII ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization )
    // to cleanup resources even in case of exceptions.
    // This greatly simplifies the code because now we don't have to manually cleanup the 
    // resources at every location in the code where we throw an exception.
    struct Resources {
        HBITMAP hImage = nullptr;
        HGDIOBJ hOldImage = nullptr;
        HDC hMemDC = nullptr;

        // This destructor will be automatically called before the function 
        // SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource() returns aswell as any locations 
        // in the code where the "throw" keyword is used to throw an exception.
        ~Resources() 
        {
            if( hMemDC ) 
            {
                if( hOldImage )
                    ::SelectObject( hMemDC, hOldImage );
                ::DeleteDC( hMemDC );
            }
            if( hImage )
                ::DeleteObject( hImage );
        }
    } res;

    // Make it possible to use nullptr as an argument for the hInstance parameter of 
    // this function. This means we will load the resources from the current executable 
    // (instead of another DLL).
    if( ! hInstance )
        hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle( nullptr );

    // Load bitmap with alpha channel from resource. 
    // Flag LR_CREATEDIBSECTION is required to create a device-independent bitmap that 
    // preserves the alpha channel.
    res.hImage = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP>(::LoadImage(
        hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( bitmapResourceId ), IMAGE_BITMAP, 
        0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION ));
    if( !res.hImage )
    {
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>(err),
            std::system_category(),
            "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: Could not load bitmap resource" );
    }

    // Get bitmap information (width, height, etc.)
    BITMAP imgInfo{ 0 };
    if( !::GetObject( res.hImage, sizeof( imgInfo ), &imgInfo ) )
    {
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>(err),
            std::system_category(),
            "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: Could not get bitmap information" );
    }

    if( imgInfo.bmBitsPixel != 32 || imgInfo.bmPlanes != 1 )
    {
        // Use a constant error value here because this is our own error condition.
        // Of course GetLastError() wouldn't return anything useful in this case.
        DWORD err = ERROR_INVALID_DATA;
        throw std::system_error( err, std::system_category(),
            "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: bitmap must be 32 bpp, single plane" );
    }

    // Create a memory DC that will be associated with the image.
    // UpdateLayeredWindow() can't use image directly, it must be in a memory DC.
    res.hMemDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC( nullptr );
    if( !res.hMemDC )
    {
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>(err), 
            std::system_category(),
            "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: Could not create memory DC" );
    }

    res.hOldImage = ::SelectObject( res.hMemDC, res.hImage );
    if( !res.hOldImage )
    {
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>(err), 
            std::system_category(),
            "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: Could not select bitmap into memory DC" );
    }

    // Assign the image to the child window, making it transparent.
    SIZE size{ imgInfo.bmWidth, imgInfo.bmHeight };
    POINT ptSrc{ 0, 0 };
    BLENDFUNCTION blend{ AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA };
    if( !::UpdateLayeredWindow( hwnd, nullptr, nullptr, &size, res.hMemDC, &ptSrc, 
                                0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA ) )
    {
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>(err), 
            std::system_category(),
            "SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource: Could not update layered window" );
    }

    // Destructor of res object will cleanup resources here!
}
```

**Usage:**

The function may be called in WM_INITDIALOG handler of your dialog box procedure, see example below. The example also shows how to handle errors.

NOTE: I'm calling MessageBoxA() here because `std::exception::what()` returns a `const char*` which is apparently a multibyte (ANSI) encoded string that contains a localized error message from the OS (with VS2015 or newer).

```
#include <sstream>

/// Dialog box procedure.
INT_PTR CALLBACK TestDialogProc( HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( lParam );
    switch( message ) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG: {
            // This is the child window where we want to show the image (e. g. a static).
            if( HWND hwndImage = ::GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_IMAGE ) ){
                try{
                    SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource( hwndImage, IDB_BITMAP1 );
                }
                catch( std::system_error& e ){
                    std::ostringstream msg;
                    msg << e.what() << std::endl << "Error code: " << e.code();
                    ::MessageBoxA( hDlg, msg.str().c_str(), "Error", MB_ICONERROR );
                }
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        case WM_COMMAND: {
            if( LOWORD( wParam ) == IDOK || LOWORD( wParam ) == IDCANCEL ){
                EndDialog( hDlg, LOWORD( wParam ) );
                return TRUE;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Pitfalls:**

Application must have a manifest resource specifying at least Win 8 compatibility:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application>
        <!-- Windows 10 --> 
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>   
    </application>
  </compatibility>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

The image to load must be a 32 bpp, top-down bitmap with premultiplied alpha channel.

A regular PNG can be converted into this format using [PixelFormer](http://www.qualibyte.com/pixelformer/) for instance. Open image, then File > Export. Select bitmap, format A8:R8:G8:B8 (32 bpp), premultiplied alpha, top-down row order.

Comment: Thank you!  Tried to upvote, but I'm too new.  Answer 1 is the definitive answer in my view.  You are pure genius on the second approach.

Comment: This makes sense. While my preference would be that by default VS2013 or VS2017 use updated controls, I can understand the reason a bit that it is not.    You are pure genius @zett42 on the second approach.   As a first time user, prior to your response, I was less enthusiastic about the site.

Comment: will be adding the manifest to all my projects!  Again, thanks, I and I'm sure the community is very grateful.

Comment: You are welcome! You should click the accept button if the answer is useful for you. I was personally interested in the layered child window stuff as I always wanted to try that out. Maybe in 15 years when our user base finally abandons Win7, I'm actually allowed to use that ;-).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the grey check box is not intuitive. I agree, there is a lot of interesting things that can be done with layered child windows.  Some customers are still on Windows XP. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Zett42's answer, a simple pragma can also direct the compiler to use the 6 0 0 0 controls rather than using the manifest file.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' " "version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```