# How to display transparent png image files on a win32 button with color same as background color

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I have a win32 window with background color blue. I have created a button on the window using the code

```
// code for creating button

hButton1= CreateWindow(_T("BUTTON"),_T("Test button"), BS_ICON  | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,800,200,228,228,hWnd, (HMENU)1,NULL,NULL);
```

I loaded a .png transparent image as button image using the code

```
// code to     
// using GDI
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);   

Gdiplus::Bitmap* m_pBitmap;
HICON hicon;
    m_pBitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"d:\\gear.png");
    m_pBitmap->GetHICON(&hicon);  
    LRESULT lr = SendMessage(hButton1,BM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_ICON,(LPARAM)hicon );

ShowWindow(hButton1,SW_SHOW);
```

Now the button is displayed with transparent .png image data with button default background color. I changed the button background color to blue. But when we load .png file , then button color changed to default color.

I need to keep the transparent area of the button the same color as the background color of the window i.e. blue. You can refer the image of my window

[image: This is the window displayed]

Comment: Maybe he doesn't know how to set the button's background color to blue as well.

Comment: *"Please share all the ideas"* is not a question, and certainly not problem statement that meets the quality requirements of Stack Overflow. Please explain the issue you are trying to solve with enough detail, so that we (and future visitors) can understand it.

Comment: @IInspectable What do you not understand about the question? Maybe asking for *specific* details would be more helpful, so OP or "we" SO users who already understand it, can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @zett42: Does the OP control the parent window? Is the OP's background always a solid color? If the answer to both of those questions is *"Yes"*, then Hans Passant has [offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310881/how-to-display-transparent-png-image-files-on-a-win32-button-with-color-same-as?noredirect=1#comment83608540_48310881) an easier solution. Without answers to those questions, we have competing solutions, and future visitors are in a pretty bad situation, trying to determine, which solution might be more appropriate.

Comment: @IInspectable Where does Hans Passant offer a solution?

Comment: @zett42: There's a hyperlink in the comment.

Comment: @IInspectable ...which just links to Hans's comment that doesn't offer a solution.

Comment: @zett42: The solution: Set the buttons background color to be the same as the parent window's background color. This can easily be deduced from that comment, no?

Comment: @IInspectable It cannot be deduced from that comment, how to set a buttons background color. AFAIK there is no way to do that apart from custom draw / owner draw.

Comment: It offers a solution, but doesn't explain, how to implement it. The [WM_CTLCOLORBTN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761849.aspx) message can be used to set a button's background brush. This still requires an owner-drawn button, but it's still easier than your proposed solution. But since we don't know, what the OP really needs, there is little value in providing this as an answer.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't know how to set the button's background color to blue as well. – Hans Passant 2  - No, I already changed background color of the button. That is the first thing we will do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK there is no simple way to make the background of a button transparent and let it only draw the icon.

One can use *[custom draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761817(v=vs.85).aspx)* to completely control the appearance of the button. There is also "owner draw" but for buttons this technique is outdated as of Windows Vista. *Custom draw* has the advantage that you don't have to modify the button styles (so you can keep `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`, for instance) and it is also more flexible as you only need to do part of the drawing if you wish so. For our use case we need to draw everything though.

To use *custom draw*, handle the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW` notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761847(v=vs.85).aspx) in the window procedure of the parent of the button. When `NMCUSTOMDRAW::dwDrawStage` equals `CDDS_PREERASE`, do your drawing and return `CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT` so Windows doesn't paint over what you have drawn.

To achieve transparency, one can call [`DrawThemeParentBackground()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773306(v=vs.85).aspx) to draw the background of the parent window before calling [`DrawIconEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648065(v=vs.85).aspx) to draw the icon transparently over the background.

## Example

Here is a complete working example program. Error handling omitted for clarity.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>  // for DrawThemeParentBackground()

#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "uxtheme.lib")

// Common controls manifest entry is required for using custom draw.
// Remove this pragma if you have already included this in the manifest of your project.
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CustomDrawButton( HWND hWnd, NMCUSTOMDRAW const& nmc );

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    // Initialize GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup( &gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL );   

    // Register window class for main window    
    WNDCLASS wc{ sizeof(wc) }; // set cbSize and zero-init all other members
    wc.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground  = CreateSolidBrush( RGB( 255, 200, 127 ) );
    wc.lpszClassName  = L"MyWindowClass";
    RegisterClassW( &wc );

    // Create main window    
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW( 0, wc.lpszClassName, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, nullptr );
    ShowWindow( hWnd, nCmdShow );

    // Create button    
    HWND hButton1 = CreateWindow( L"BUTTON", L"Test button", BS_ICON | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 50, 50, 228, 228, hWnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL );

    // Assign image to button
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* m_pBitmap;
    HICON hicon;
    m_pBitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"test.png");
    m_pBitmap->GetHICON(&hicon);  
    LRESULT lr = SendMessage( hButton1, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hicon );

    // Standard message loop        
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            auto pnm = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>( lParam );
            if( pnm->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW )
            {
                // NOTE: you should check if pnm->hwndFrom really is the button
                // you want to draw. Not required in this example because
                // we only have one control.
                LRESULT res = CustomDrawButton( pnm->hwndFrom, *reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>( lParam ) );
                if( res != 0 )
                    return res;
            }
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}   

LRESULT CustomDrawButton( HWND hWnd, NMCUSTOMDRAW const& nmc )
{
    switch( nmc.dwDrawStage )
    {
        case CDDS_PREERASE:
        {
            RECT rc{}; GetClientRect( hWnd, &rc );

            // Draw the background of the parent window.
            DrawThemeParentBackground( hWnd, nmc.hdc, &rc );

            // Get the icon we assigned to the button.    
            HICON hIcon = reinterpret_cast<HICON>( SendMessage( hWnd, BM_GETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, 0 ) );

            // Draw the icon transparently over the background.
            DrawIconEx( nmc.hdc, 0, 0, hIcon, rc.right, rc.bottom, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL );

            // Tell Windows we have drawn everything by ourselfs.    
            return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my button image ("test.png"):

[image: Button image]

And this is how the final result looks like:

[image: Window screenshot]

Comment: @SabuViswamoni Sorry, no. If you have a follow-up question just ask here in comments or better yet post a new question.

Comment: Yes , I have a follow up question. I am testing a different scenario. I just tried this by creating the button over another static control in the main window. An another .png file is loaded on the static control. The button should be transparent with image in the static control instead of main window color.

Comment: @SabuViswamoni If you just want to display a background image behind the button, I would draw the background image by the parent window (handle `WM_PRINTCLIENT` and `WM_PAINT`). Otherwise you could try to make the button a layered child window, which I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603066/7571258) for a static control but I don't know if this works for buttons aswell. This technique requires Win 8 at least.

Comment: Hi zett42, I checked the sample( you given to solve button transparency over static control)  and it is not suitable for my application. My application is purely Win32 application and not having any resource IDs, so I cannot use SetLayeredWindowFromBitmapResource. I will load .png image files from external files.I will post a new question with my exact requirement.

Comment: Pls check the question and attached image in the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412063/creating-transparant-buttons-over-static-control-in-win32