# Windows button ignores alpha channel for fully transparent image

Tags: winapi, button, bitmap, gdi, alpha

- I have a radio button that should display an image (style `BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON|BS_PUSHLIKE|BS_BITMAP`).
- I create a bitmap via `CreateDIBSection` (using a `BITMAPINFO` with `BI_RGB`) and obtain a pointer to the raw pixels via the `ppvBits`, so that I can manipulate them freely.
- I use `BM_SETIMAGE` to set the button's image to the bitmap I created.

So far, I can set the *RGB and alpha* by manipulating the pixels by hand. I tested that even semi-transparent (non-premultiplied) alpha values look good.

As far as I can tell, everything works, except if all pixels in the image are transparent. In that case, the button apparently ignores the alpha value, simply displaying a rectangle with each pixel having the respective color with full opacity.

I [found a hint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101021-00/?p=12483/) that Windows - at least in some cases - actually seems to interpret images whose pixels' alpha values are all 0 as completely opaque images:

> When the window manager sees a 32bpp bitmap, it looks at the alpha
>   channel. If it's all zeroes, then it assumes that the image is in 0RGB
>   format; otherwise it assumes it is in ARGB format

Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Why would you want to 'display' a completely transparent image?

Comment: @PaulSanders: To serve as a placeholder, for example. Or simply because it's easier to not write code, that tries to analyze an image prior to deciding, whether it should be displayed. Less code to write, less chance of introducing bugs, and - most importantly - less code to read.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, in this case it would seem that one has no choice.

Comment: In the call to `CreateDIBSection`, try to use `BITMAPV4HEADER` with `BI_BITFIELDS` to specify the alpha mask. This could allow the system to determine that the bitmap actually is in `ARGB` format, without using heuristics. If that doesn't work, a workaround could be to set the top-left pixel alpha value to 1, which I bet nobody will notice.

Comment: Another option: use [custom draw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48312005/7571258)

Comment: @zett42: Thanks for the suggestions. Regarding `BITMAPV4HEADER`/`BI_BITFIELDS`: Good idea, but no luck. Setting the top-left pixel alpha to 1 is no option, since the my images are so small, that every pixel counts. Custom draw might be an alternative, but seems to be a bit over the top for a simple image and I already have `BM_SETIMAGE`. Probably I'll go with the "manual" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Yes! In Raymond's post! :) That's often the way of it, no?

If you look at the foot of the page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/button-styles) you will find a comments box.  If you raise your concerns there then MS will most likely fix their documentation.  See [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/308) for an example of the process they usually follow if they consider the problem serious enough to fix.