# EnableWindow(FALSE) for CListCtrl doesn't change the appearance of it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

when I try to EnableWindow(FALSE) for CListCtrl I am not able to perform any action on it but its appearance doesn't change as CButton or any other. is there any way to change the appearance of CListCtrl.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think CListCtrl is intended to change on disabling but you can use WM_ENABLE message to change the appearance yourself.

Comment: WM_ENABLE lets you catch when the control is being disabled and you should change the appearance as it fits your use-case. For example make the background grey.

Comment: @SayedMomeen `CListCtrl::SetBkColor()` or use [custom draw](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/79/neat-stuff-to-do-in-list-controls-using-custom-dra) to have full control over the appearance.

Comment: @zett42 `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` is this possible to use on CListCtrl ??

Comment: @SayedMomeen Layered child windows are possible since Windows 8 if you add an application manifest with appropriate compatibility element(s). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603066/7571258).