# Qt transparent child window with WS_EX_LAYERED always fails

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, libvlc, win32gui

I'm integrating libVLC in a Qt Quick application on Windows by creating a child window and passing the handle of the window to libVLC to render the video.

This works fine.

However, I'm trying to create the child window with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style in order to apply some transparency to it. I simply cannot get it working.

Here's the code:

```
    const auto parentWindow = quickWindow()->winId(); //The native window handle

    const auto windowClassName = QString("VLCWindow-").append(QString::number(reinterpret_cast<int64_t>(this), 16)).toStdWString();
    WNDCLASSEXW wcx = {};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProcW;
    wcx.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(::GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    wcx.hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    wcx.lpszClassName = windowClassName.data();
    if (!::RegisterClassExW(&wcx)) {
        const auto lastError = ::GetLastError();
        if (lastError != ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
            qCritical() << "RegisterClassEx failed:" << lastError;
            return;
        }
    }
    const auto nativeWindowHandle = ::CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_LAYERED, wcx.lpszClassName, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 0, 0, 0, 0, reinterpret_cast<HWND>(parentWindow), nullptr, ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
    if (nativeWindowHandle) {
        qInfo() << "Created native window for VLC rendering; handle:" << nativeWindowHandle;
    } else {
        auto err = ::GetLastError();
        qCritical() << "CreateWindowEx failed:" << err;
        return;
    }
```

The above `CreateWindowExW` always fails with `GetLastEror()` returning 0!
 As soon as I remove `WS_EX_LAYERED`, everything is fine, but I need the `WS_EX_LAYERED`.
I am running the code on a Windows 10, so the limitation of `WS_EX_LAYERED` on a pre-Windows 8 doesn't apply.

I tried the following:

- calling `CreateWindowsExW(0, ...`  (which succeeds) and then call `SetWindowLongPtrW` to apply `WS_EX_LAYERED`, but `SetWindowLongPtrW` returns 0 and `GetLastError` also returns 0!
- passing my own `lpfnWndProc` to `RegisterClassEx` where I logged all the message types received; the only message I get is a `WM_NCDESTROY`, without any `WM_NCCREATE` sent before!

Many thanks!

Comment: Make sure to add `<Compatibility>` element to your manifest to specify Win8/8.1/10 compatibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603066/7571258 (at the end of the answer).

Comment: @zett42 Indeed, adding the manifest did the trick, thank you! I actually tried to do it at first, but I couldn't find any Qt-qmake documentation, so I was not doing it properly :)

Comment: Great, so we can close this as dupe.